# When to use an if statement after get_posts?

Tags: functions, get-posts, codex

Whilst looking through the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) for the `get_posts` function, I noticed that in the majority of the examples they do not show an if statement after call to `get_posts`

Example:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
    <div>
        <?php the_date(); ?>
        <br />
        <?php the_title(); ?>   
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
<?php
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

And:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' =>'any', 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );

**if ( $attachments ) {**
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    echo apply_filters( 'the_title' , $attachment->post_title );
    the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false );
    }
}
?>
```

I'm not sure if the codex is assuming that you will always have posts so no need to check?

I personally always use it, but wonder if someone could enlighten me on if its necessary. When is a right time to use the if statement?

Comment: It's not necessary to me as I tested without if and I could not get any warnings/php errors.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion we cannot guarantee the post existence in db for a specific query. maybe it returns an empty array. so its best practice to use the conditional statement. plus i think we are dealing with an array so to check the empty array  we should use php `empty` function.

for example:

```
if ( !empty( $attachments ) ) {
  foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
   // do some stuff here.
  }
}
else {
  _e('Sorry! No posts found.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `get_posts()` can return an empty array

In that case the foreach loop is like:

```
foreach ( [] as $post ) 
{
    // ...
}
```

where there's nothing to loop over. This code is valid.

If the code snippet is like:

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) 
{
    // <li>...</li>
}
echo '</ul>';
```

then we need to check if `$postslist` is non-empty:

```
if( $postslist )
{   
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $postslist as $post ) 
    {
        // <li>...</li>
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

to avoid displaying an empty `<ul></ul>` list.

This is an example, out of many, where it would make sense to check if the post list is non-empty, but it's not required, like if you only need the count:

```
echo count( (array) $postslist );
```